# I can't fill the horizontal gap between two flex items in a row

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am designing a web page and I tried to stack a clip-art image and description in a row in flex. There is a gap between those two which doesn't go away despite adding justify-content. I have used color to better visualize the situation.

[The faulty part](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PsaCG.png)

```css
        body {
          background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
        }
        nav {
          display: inline;
          text-align: right;
        }
        nav > * {
          margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
          font-family: serif;
          text-decoration: none;
          color: black;
        }
        img {
          width: 25%;
          height: auto;
          display: inline;
          text-align: left;
          margin: 0px 600px 0px 0px;
        }
        header {
          display: block;
        
          margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
          width: 100%;
        }
        div {
          display: block;
          width: 70%;
          margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
          text-align: center;
        }
        #email {
          background-color: white;
          border: black solid;
          width: 300px;
          height: 25px;
          margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }
        #submit {
          width: 200px;
          height: 25px;
          display: block;
          margin: auto;
          border: solid black;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
        #features {
          display: block;
        }
        #clip {
          width: 100px;
          height: 100px;
        }
        section {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: row;
          margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px;
          background-color: yellow;
        }
        article {
          display: flex;
          flex-direction: column;
          background-color: pink;
         
        }
        article > * {
          margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
        }
```

```html
      <body>
      <header>
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects- fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="original trombones">
        <nav>
          <a href="">Features</a>
          <a href="">How it works</a>
          <a href="">Pricing</a>
        </nav>
      </header>
      <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Hand-crafted, home-made masterpieces</h1>
        <form id="form">
        <label for="email"></label>
        <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
        <button type="submit" form="form" target="_blank"id="submit"><strong>Let's get started!</strong></button></form>
        </div>
      <div2 id="features">
        <section>
          <img id="clip" src="https://shop.digitemb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/V-20793-Elegant-Prince-Crown-Silhouette-Vector-Art.jpg">
          <article>
            <h3>Premium Materials</h3>
            <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <section>
          <img id="clip" src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/85-853916_fast-delivery-icon-png.png">
          <article>
            <h3>Fast Shipping</h3>
            <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        <section>
          <img id="clip" src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/iulika1/iulika11810/iulika1181000043/126717986-project-management-icon-vector-illustration.jpg?ver=6">
          <article>
            <h3>Quality Assurance</h3>
            <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
      </div2>
      
    </body>
```

This is the full code. And I am trying to get the items of 'section' in '#features' element to be close together.

Comment: Please provide your full CSS, including the wrapper element

Comment: I added full code @GalAbra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I could understand, that you want to display your content in one row after removing the gap.
Following is the solution to fulfill your requirement.I changed `CSS` only.Also updated `HTML` document structure by including `head` tag and `title` tag and included style within the head tag which is proper way to write `HTML` page.
Complete code is as follows;

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        body {
            background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220);
        }

        nav {
            display: inline;
            text-align: right;
        }

            nav > * {
                margin: 0px 20px 0px 0px;
                font-family: serif;
                text-decoration: none;
                color: black;
            }

        img {
            width: 25%;
            height: auto;
            display: inline;
            text-align: left;
            /*margin: 0px 600px 0px 0px;*/
        }

        header img {
            /*        width: 25%;
        height: auto;
        display: inline;
        text-align: left;*/
            margin: 0px 600px 0px 0px;
        }

        header {
            display: block;
            margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            width: 100%;
        }

        div {
            display: block;
            width: 70%;
            margin: 0px 200px 0px 200px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #email {
            background-color: white;
            border: black solid;
            width: 300px;
            height: 25px;
            margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
        }

        #submit {
            width: 200px;
            height: 25px;
            display: block;
            margin: auto;
            border: solid black;
            background-color: yellow;
            margin-bottom: 50px;
        }

        #features {
            display: flex;
        }

        #clip {
            width: 100px;
            height: 100px;
        }

        section {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: row;
            /* margin: 50px 100px 50px 100px; */
            background-color: yellow;
            /* margin: 0px 100px;*/
        }

        article {
            display: flex;
            flex-direction: column;
            background-color: pink;
        }

            article > * {
                margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
            }
    </style>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <img src="https://cdn.freecodecamp.org/testable-projects- fcc/images/product-landing-page-logo.png" alt="original trombones">
        <nav>
            <a href="">Features</a>
            <a href="">How it works</a>
            <a href="">Pricing</a>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <div>
        <h1 style="text-align: center;">Hand-crafted, home-made masterpieces</h1>
        <form id="form">
            <label for="email"></label>
            <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Enter your email" required>
            <button type="submit" form="form" target="_blank" id="submit"><strong>Let's get started!</strong></button>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div2 id="features">
        <section>
            <img id="clip" src="https://shop.digitemb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/V-20793-Elegant-Prince-Crown-Silhouette-Vector-Art.jpg">
            <article>
                <h3>Premium Materials</h3>
                <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section>
            <img id="clip" src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/85-853916_fast-delivery-icon-png.png">
            <article>
                <h3>Fast Shipping</h3>
                <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
        <section>
            <img id="clip" src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/iulika1/iulika11810/iulika1181000043/126717986-project-management-icon-vector-illustration.jpg?ver=6">
            <article>
                <h3>Quality Assurance</h3>
                <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
            </article>
        </section>
    </div2>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** Also if you want to display your content in multiple lines i.e single in one row, then just make following changes in my modified/updated `code`;

```
#features {
    display: block;
}
```

Remove background color from `section` and `article`. i.e `Yellow` and `pink`.Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Thank you the edits! It totally helped. Apparently, the problem was with 'img' element and the display attribute of the '#feature' element. Also, thank you for the suggestions related to neatness!

Comment: You are welcome. If it solves your problem then accept my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 0):

*try this*

```
section 
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: yellow;
  
}
article 
{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

Comment: Thank you @Waids  though it only removed the margins around section and didnt close the gap.

Comment: Welcome bro
And do up +

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote your code, consider the following:

### Snippet

> You have complete control over your paddings and margins in `.flex-container > img, article`

```css
html {background-color: rgb(220, 220, 220)}
#features{width:100%;text-align:center}
#clip{height:200px;width:200px}
.flex-container {
  margin:auto;
  max-width:700px;
  display: flex;
}
.flex-container > img, article {
  background-color: #f1f1f1;
  margin: 10px 5px 0 0;
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 15px;
}
```

```html
<div id="features">
        
        <section class="flex-container">
          <img id="clip" src="https://shop.digitemb.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/06/V-20793-Elegant-Prince-Crown-Silhouette-Vector-Art.jpg">
          <article>
            <h3>Premium Materials</h3>
            <p>Our trombones use the shiniest brass which is sourced locally. This will increase the longevity of your purchase.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        
        <section class="flex-container">
          <img id="clip" src="https://www.clipartkey.com/mpngs/m/85-853916_fast-delivery-icon-png.png">
          <article>
            <h3>Fast Shipping</h3>
            <p>We make sure you recieve your trombone as soon as we have finished making it. We also provide free returns if you are not satisfied.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        
        <section class="flex-container">
          <img id="clip" src="https://us.123rf.com/450wm/iulika1/iulika11810/iulika1181000043/126717986-project-management-icon-vector-illustration.jpg?ver=6">
          <article >
            <h3>Quality Assurance</h3>
            <p>For every purchase you make, we will ensure there are no damages or faults and we will check and test the pitch of your instrument.</p>
          </article>
        </section>
        
</div>
```

**Note**: if you want to learn more about flexbox I suggest [this page](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp)

Comment: Thank you for the edit, and beautifying it too! It helped!

Comment: I am a beginner and your edits gave some very useful insights!